# Error handling techniques for nested methods that can throw exceptions

Tags: c#

I have 2 different approaches I'm using to handle error state or `Exceptions` from within nested functions.  Take the following code for example:

```
public void Func1()
{
    try
    {
        Func2(); 
        //... continued logic if no exception was encountered 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

}

public void Func2()
{
    try
    {
        Func3();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In the above sample, `Func1` needs to know if `Func2` (and other methods `Func2` calls) have thrown an exception, so that it can continue with execution.  This appears to me to be an obvious code-smell and it's something I'd like to avoid doing.  Here's the next option I've tried:

```
public void Func1()
{
    try
    {
        bool success = Func2();
        if (!success)
        {
            //... continued logic if no exception was encountered
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

public bool Func2()
{
    try
    {
        bool success = Func3();
        if (!success) return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using this second method, the nested functions return a `boolean` to determine state and whether or not the calling function should continue.  This also doesn't *feel* right to me.  I'd really like suggestions on ways to handle situations like this where I'm calling nested functions (particularly when they return `void` because they do unrelated processing to the class).  Thanks!

**EDIT**: updated from pseudo-code to valid C#.

Comment: Pseudocode is off-topic on Code Review. _We_'ll be happy to take a look at your real code.

Comment: There are very few variations from what I posted to the real code, but I'll make it valid C#.

Comment: I'm still not sure about it. Now it's no longer pseudocode but a hypothetical one which would still be off-topic. If you cannot provide a real example then I'm afraid your question is better asked at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Code Review tries to improve working code rather then answering philosophical questions ;-)

Comment: I see.  I'll keep that in mind for next time.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us more code? I believe it can be split into smaller functions doing the work and returning data, then you could handle exceptions there or return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If shortly, using exceptions is not a code-smell.

---

In my opinion using bool return values is appropriate for methods that are purposed for checking some conditions. Examples:

```
bool CanFunc2BeCalled() {  ... }
bool TryParse(string s, out ... value) { ... }
```

Such methods specifically designed to return `bool`. It is the main job they do.

If a method should perform some actions and during its execution an exception can be occured I would not return bool to indicate a failure. An exception is the right choice for these cases.

Exceptions is a native conception of .NET so don't be afraid of them :) Also with good XML comment on methods you always know what exceptions the method can throw:

```
///<summary>
///...
///</summary>
///<exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Description of failure.</exception>
void Func2() { ... }
```

So if you are able to check that call of a method can cause an exception before its execution, create the method for checking some conditions and call it before:

```
private bool CanFunc2BeCalled() {  ... }

public void Func1()
{
    if (!CanFunc2BeCalled())
        return;

    Func2();    
}
```

But if you can't check if the `Func2` can be safely called before its execution then dealing with exceptions is a good way and I would stick with it.

Comment: Good summary.  I've played around with different styles and using baked in `Exception` handling still seems to be the cleanest and most straight-forward way to do this.